# Recording an iPad screen press: Location and time

Tags: html, ipad

I would like to record the physical surfaces a dr touches when they do their patient care in a hospital room. I think having a layout of the room (or even just a list of room surfaces) on an iPad could be useful if I can make an app or HTML canvas so I can tap the equivalent surface when the Dr touches it in the real room.

In the past I have written down the surfaces one by one with a time next to them- so this is the output I'd like ultimately:
**e.g.**

Door hand: 09:27:39

Table 09:28:16

Patient 09:28:31

etc

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Hi Austen. I'm not after code. I'm wondering if it is possible to do what I'm looking for. One way I thought of was to just draw a pic of the room layout. Then record the screen somehow and tap the surfaces as they are touched. I would then have to watch the recordings and transcribe them afterwards. Seems very laborious.

Comment: Yes it is possible, there are various methods to achieve what you are after. However this *may* not be the best place to ask as *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the image `<map>` HTML feature, read how it works here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Look a demo example I set up for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/96d7pvso/

```
<img src="..." usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area href="javascript:ClickOnImageMap('window1');" coords="167,85,103,40" shape="rect">
    <area href="javascript:ClickOnImageMap('window2');" coords="198,5,248,0,285,45,236,54" shape="poly">
    <area href="javascript:ClickOnImageMap('chair');" coords="43,106,43,142,73,141,78,90,61,91,61,100" shape="poly">
    <area href="javascript:ClickOnImageMap('bed');" coords="191,120,239,166,299,166,299,130,236,102,191,100" shape="poly">
</map>
```

Once you have the picture or illustration of the room, use a map tool to generate your map ([like this one](https://www.image-map.net/)), and write your script to execute what you need. In my example there is a javascript function executed every time an area is clicked, and I pass the area name as string to the function.

Comment: Ohh wow that looks fantastic, thank you so much, even more than I had hoped! This might be a silly question: Does the jsfiddle website allow you to write those outputs to file locally or remotely?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately jsfiddle is just a frontend scripting playground, you can't write any local/remote file from there. To write files you need a backend script, for example, in PHP or NodeJS. 
Alternatively, if you want to use jsfiddle, you can consider to store data in a database and setup a restapi service (or use a ready to use service like https://restdb.io ), so you can use ajax calls to store data

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I think jsfiddle is ok. I've signed up for restdb.io and going to see what I need to do. If you had to estimate, how long would it take for a newbie to serverside things to write what you suggest? Alternatively, I can copy paste the output from the js code and save it to file by hand (definitely not elegant though!).

Comment: No worries @HCAI, mmm it could take a while to understand javascript and ajax scripting for a newbie. So, in your case, I would recommend to start using the free plan on Firebase, and you can follow this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start on how to connect the frontend (on jsfiddle) to your firebase db. There are a lot of steps, but at least is well documented!

Comment: Ah, another solution, if you just need to store the data no matter where, is to use the html5 db, it's a database that store the data in the browser (similar to the browser cache or temporary files), so the data are not shared on the web or stored in any server, only the user's browser. But you need to create also an interface to read/export the data: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_indexeddb

Comment: Many thanks again for all of your help with this. I'm just trying this out in safari on an ipad4 and finding that no scroll bar appears after you continue to touch surfaces. Do you think this is a safari issue on ios?